# Override field name de-serialization in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have a service which uses autoquery and has a response dto which looks like this

```
[DataContract(Name = "list_item", Namespace = "")]
public class ListItem
{
    [DataMember(Name = "list_id",)]
    public String ListId { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "first_name")]
    public String FirstName  { get; set; }
```

}

when I use autoquery without spaces it returns the correct result, but with spaces the autoquery doesnt work 
http://localhost/search?listid=12345

In the apphost.cs I added the following code

```
 private void ConfigSerializer(Container container)
    {                       
        JsConfig.PropertyConvention = PropertyConvention.Lenient;
        JsConfig.EmitLowercaseUnderscoreNames = true;
```

}

But still I cannot get the results when I use the underscore.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This [AutoQuery test](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/7497c297670b2d69ca9cfbdc526ac69170c8bc3d) shows AutoQuery supporting a Request DTO with custom alias fields as seen in this AutoQuery Service:

```
[DataContract]
[Route("/rockstars")]
public class QueryRockstars : QueryBase<Rockstar>
{
    [DataMember(Name = "first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Which can be called with this test:

```
var request = new QueryRockstars { FirstName = "Jimi" };

//QueryString used:
Assert.That(request.ToGetUrl(), 
    Is.EqualTo("/rockstars?first_name=Jimi"));

var response = client.Get(request);

Assert.That(response.Results.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
Assert.That(response.Results[0].FirstName, Is.EqualTo("Jimi"));
```

ServiceStack has also been updated to look at any matching any aliases on the underlying table so now you can use field conventions on the query table, e.g:

```
[Route("/search")]
public class QueryPerson : QueryBase<Person> {}

[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

var response = "http://example.org/search"
    .AddQueryParam("first_name", "Jimi")
    .GetJsonFromUrl()
    .FromJson<QueryResponse<Person>>();

response.PrintDump();
```

It also supports implicit mapping using the `JsConfig.EmitLowercaseUnderscoreNames` convention, e.g:

```
JsConfig.EmitLowercaseUnderscoreNames = true;

var response = "http://example.org/search"
    .AddQueryParam("last_name", "Hendrix")
    .GetJsonFromUrl()
    .FromJson<QueryResponse<Person>>();
```

These changes are available from **v4.0.41+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).